# Aquire &'a T from Option<T<'a>>

Tags: reference, rust, borrow-checker

I'm afraid this may be very basic but I haven't been able to figure it out on my own. I have this map:

```
subscriptions_map: HashMap<SubscriptionKey, Subscription<'a>>
```

and this vector:

```
subscriptions: Vec<&'a Subscription<'a>>,
```

I want to insert a value into the `HashMap` and a reference to the same item into the vector. I've tried to do it like this:

```
let subs: &'a Subscription = &self.subscriptions_map.insert(id, item).unwrap();
self.subscriptions.push(subs);
```

But it gets this error:

```
error: borrowed value does not live long enough
         let subs: &'a Subscription = &self.subscriptions_map.insert(id, item).unwrap();
                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 40:70...
     pub fn add_subscription(&'a mut self, mut item: Subscription<'a>) {
         let id = item.get_id();

         let _lock = self.lock.lock().unwrap();

         let subs: &'a Subscription = &self.subscriptions_map.insert(id, item).unwrap();
 ...
note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 2 at 45:87
         let subs: &'a Subscription = &self.subscriptions_map.insert(id, item).unwrap();
         self.subscriptions.push(subs);
     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

I guess my question boils down to: If I have an `Option<T<'a>>`, how can I get a `&'a T`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct)

Comment: @PeterLudvigsen: What you are looking for is impossible (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct). Storing one item will *permanently* anchor the parent `struct`, preventing any further borrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`HashMap.insert()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.insert) returns the **old** value for the given key, not the value you just passed. That's not what you want!

After you've inserted an item into the `HashMap`, you must call `HashMap.get()` to retrieve a pointer to the value. As `HashMap.insert()` takes ownership of both the key and the value, we need to pass a clone of `id` to `insert()` so we can use the original `id` for the `get()` call. (If the type of `id` is `Copy`, you may omit the call to `clone()` and let the compiler copy the value.)

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash, Clone)]
struct SubscriptionKey;
struct Subscription<'a>(&'a ());

struct Foo<'a> {
    subscriptions_map: HashMap<SubscriptionKey, Subscription<'a>>,
    subscriptions: Vec<&'a Subscription<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn add(&'a mut self, id: SubscriptionKey, item: Subscription<'a>) {
        self.subscriptions_map.insert(id.clone(), item);
        let subs = self.subscriptions_map.get(&id).unwrap();
        self.subscriptions.push(subs);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let subscription_data = &();

    let mut f = Foo {
        subscriptions_map: HashMap::new(),
        subscriptions: Vec::new(),
    };

    f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data));
}
```

This works fine, but it falls apart if we try to add another subscription. If we do this:

```
fn main() {
    let subscription_data = &();
    let subscription_data2 = &();

    let mut f = Foo {
        subscriptions_map: HashMap::new(),
        subscriptions: Vec::new(),
    };

    f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data));
    f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data2));
}
```

the compiler gives the following messages:

```
<anon>:30:5: 30:6 error: cannot borrow `f` as mutable more than once at a time [E0499]
<anon>:30     f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data2));
              ^
<anon>:30:5: 30:6 help: see the detailed explanation for E0499
<anon>:29:5: 29:6 note: previous borrow of `f` occurs here; the mutable borrow prevents subsequent moves, borrows, or modification of `f` until the borrow ends
<anon>:29     f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data));
              ^
<anon>:31:2: 31:2 note: previous borrow ends here
<anon>:20 fn main() {
...
<anon>:31 }
          ^
```

What's going on? Why does the mutable borrow persist after the first call to `Foo::add`?

The problem comes from the definition of the `subscriptions` field. It's defined as a `Vec<&'a Subscription<'a>>`. Satisfying the `'a` in `Subscription<'a>` is easy, since we receive the object with the correct lifetime in `add`. Satisfying the `'a` in `&'a ...` is harder, since the `Subscription<'a>` value doesn't have a fixed address until we insert it into `subscriptions_map` (in my example, a `Subscription<'a>` is moved from a local variable in `main()` to a parameter in `Foo::add()` to inside `self.subscriptions_map`).

In order to satisfy the outer `'a`, `Foo::add()` must define its `self` parameter as `&'a mut self`. If we defined it as `&mut self`, we couldn't be sure that the references we get out of `subscriptions_map` would live long enough (their lifetime could be shorter than `'a`).

However, by inserting a `&'a Subscription<'a>` inside of a `Foo<'a>`, we are effectively *locking down* the `Foo` for further modifications, since we are now storing a borrow from `self.subscriptions_map` in `self.subscriptions`. Consider what would happen if we inserted another item in `subscriptions_map`: how can we be sure that the `HashMap` won't move its items around in memory? If the `HashMap` does move our item, the pointer in `self.subscriptions` wouldn't be updated automatically and would be dangling.

Now, suppose that we have this buggy `remove()` method:

```
impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn remove(&mut self, id: &SubscriptionKey) {
        self.subscriptions_map.remove(id);
    }
}
```

This method compiles fine. However, if we tried to call this on a `Foo` on which we called `add()` earlier, then `self.subscriptions` would contain a dangling reference to an item that used to be in `self.subscriptions_map`.

So the reason why the mutable borrow persists after calling `add()` is that, since the `'a` in `Foo<'a>` is equal to the lifetime of the `Foo<'a>` itself, the compiler sees that the object borrows from itself. As you know, we can't have a mutable borrow and another borrow (mutable or not) active at the same time, so Rust prevents us from taking a mutable borrow on `f` while `f` itself retains an active borrow. In fact, since we used a method that takes `self` by mutable reference, Rust assumes that `Foo<'a>` stores a mutable reference, even though that's not the case, since Rust only looks at the signatures to determine borrows (this is to ensure that changing a private field from `&'a T` to `&'a mut T` doesn't cause borrow checking failures to you and, if you're developing a library, to your users). Since the type of an object never changes, the `Foo<'a>` is locked for the rest of its lifetime.

Now, what can you do? Clearly, you can't usefully have a `Vec<&'a Subscription<'a>>` in your struct. `HashMap` provides a [`values()`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.values) iterator, but it enumerates the values in an unspecified order, so it won't help you if you want to enumerate the values in the order in which they were added. Instead of using borrowed pointers, you could use [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct SubscriptionKey;
struct Subscription<'a>(&'a ());

struct Foo<'a> {
    subscriptions_map: HashMap<SubscriptionKey, Rc<Subscription<'a>>>,
    subscriptions: Vec<Rc<Subscription<'a>>>,
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn add(&mut self, id: SubscriptionKey, item: Subscription<'a>) {
        let item = Rc::new(item);
        self.subscriptions_map.insert(id, item.clone());
        self.subscriptions.push(item);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let subscription_data = &();

    let mut f = Foo {
        subscriptions_map: HashMap::new(),
        subscriptions: Vec::new(),
    };

    f.add(SubscriptionKey, Subscription(subscription_data));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting a second subscription? I did, and it does not work.